# How to check whether particular contact in address Book has been updated and reflect it on app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, contacts

Hi in app I am fetching contacts from address book and once they are updated storing it realm db.This is the code to get all contacts from address book.

```
func getAllContactsFromAddressBook() {
    do {
        let contactsFetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey as NSString,
                                                                       CNContactFamilyNameKey as NSString,
                                                                       CNContactImageDataKey as NSString,
                                                                       CNContactImageDataAvailableKey as NSString,
                                                                       CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as NSString,
                                                                       CNContactEmailAddressesKey as NSString,
                                                                       CNContactOrganizationNameKey as NSString,
                                                                       CNContactJobTitleKey as NSString,
                                                                       CNContactSocialProfilesKey as NSString ])
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: contactsFetchRequest, usingBlock: { (cnContact, error) in

        if cnContact.givenName == "", cnContact.familyName == "", cnContact.emailAddresses.count == 0 {
        } else {
            if realmStore.findContact(byId: cnContact.identifier) == nil {
                let contact = Contact()
                contact.id = cnContact.identifier
                _ = realmStore.create(contact: contact)
            }
            if let contact = realmStore.findContact(byId: cnContact.identifier) {
                do {
                    try realmStore.write {
                        contact.firstName = cnContact.givenName
                        contact.lastName = cnContact.familyName
                        contact.phoneNumber.removeAll()
                        contact.phoneNumber.append(objectsIn: cnContact.phoneNumbers.map({
                            let p = PhoneNumber()
                            p.phoneNumber = $0.value.stringValue
                            return p
                        }))
                        contact.email.removeAll()
                        contact.email.append(objectsIn: cnContact.emailAddresses.map({
                            let e = Email()
                            let email = $0.value as String
                            e.email = email == "" ? nil : email
                            return e
                        }))
                        contact.organization = cnContact.organizationName
                        contact.jobTitle = cnContact.jobTitle
                        contact.fromLinkedIn = cnContact.socialProfiles.filter({ $0.value.service == "LinkedIn" ? true : false }).first != nil ? true : false
                        if cnContact.imageDataAvailable == true {
                            contact.profileImageBlob = cnContact.imageData
                        }
                    }

                    contact.updatePriortyScore()
                }
                catch {
                    print("Couldn't update contact")
                }
            }




        }
    })
} catch {
    print(error)
}
}
```

Fetching of contacts works fine , but each time view is loaded its fetching all contact list from address book which takes time , so is there a way which will notify me specific contact in address which has been changed or if new contact has been added to address book so realm list can be updated.

Comment: There is no way to detect the specific contact. you can use global queue to fetching the contacts and update the table view after complete fetching contacts. then it will not freeze the view.

Comment: ok . so I will have to fetch all contacts  first each time the view is loaded in order to check any change in address book

Comment: Yes, you fetch the contacts in background threads or global queue. Then it will not block the view rendering.

Comment: Observe `CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: Is there a way to catch particular contact from address book which has been updated ?? And I have implemented observer in my code so anytime I am editind and contact my app catches it .

Comment: did you find anything? I just wanted to know how to get updated contacts while app is killed